# Filter out null strings and empty strings insparksql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Okay i have some data where i want to filter out all null and empty values. So  i used simple sql commands to first filter out the null values.

```
hiveContext.sql("select username from daten where username is not null").show()
```

What i get is something like this.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [username: array<string>]
```

username

```
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|              []|
|              []|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|              []|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|[dirk.staszak.3]|
|              []|
|              []|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
|          [null]|
```

So still some null entrys in there. I don t know why ?

Is there a way to filter out this null entrys and additional  filter out all empty Strings by using sparksql ? I thought about filter by the length of the strings but sparksql is not supporting len function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe from the given table and use filter in spark sql to accomplish the task
    `dataframe.filter("username is not null and username !='null'")`